# A class of Kripke frames which preserves validity

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, lo.logic, order-theory, modal-logic

The background of our discussion is intuitionistic logic, i.e. the following definitions are intuitionistic Kripke frame.

For $1\leq s\leq n-2$, the frame $\mathcal{C}_n(s)$ denotes the frame which is shown in Fig.1. It is formed by the set:
$$
\left\{(i, j)\in \omega \times \omega \mid (i=0, 0 \leq j \leq 1) \vee (1 \leq i \leq n-2,  i \neq s, 0 \leq j \leq 3)\vee (i=s, j=0) \vee (i=n-1, j=0)\right\},
$$
with the accessibility relation described in

[image]

Assuming $\psi$ is a formula with $m$ variables and $n$ is a sufficiently large number.
I want to construct a class of frames $\{\mathcal{A}_n(x)\}$ with index $x$, which satisfies:

1. For any $x$, every point $u$ in $\mathcal{A}_n(x)$ with a depth of $u$ equal to 2 has a branching degree of 2, and every point $u$ with a depth greater than 2 has a branching degree greater than or equal to 3.
2. If for **every** $x$, we have $\mathcal{A}_n(x) \nvDash \psi$, then there **exists** $s\leq n$ such that $\mathcal{C}_n(s) \nvDash \psi$.

Thus every formula $\phi(p_1, ... , p_t)$ which is valid in all $\{\mathcal{C}_{n'}(s)\}$, must be valid in some $\mathcal{A}_{n'}(x)$.

I posted a related question on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449276/preserve-validity-between-the-two-kripke-frames) which was solved by Emil Jeřábek. One could look at [Emil Jeřábek's solution](https://mathoverflow.net/a/449306/507284) to find out that the frame $\mathcal{C}_n$ can not realize it.

My attempt to build $\{\mathcal{A}_n(x)\}$ is:

For $2\leq x\leq n-2$, the frame $\{\mathcal{A}_n(x)\}$ denotes the frame which is shown in Fig.2. It is formed by the set:
$$
\left\{(i, j)\in \omega \times \omega \mid (i=0, 0 \leq j \leq 1) \vee (1 \leq i \leq n-2, 0 \leq j \leq 3)\vee (i=n-1, j=0)\right\},
$$
with the accessibility relation described in

[image]

where $(x,0)$, $(x,1)$, $(x,2)$, $(x,3)$ can see every nodes $(i, j)$ with $i \leq x-1$.

For the given formula $\psi(p_1, ..., p_m)$, there will be some levels, e.g. $(i,0)$, $(i,1)$, $(i,2)$, $(i,3)$, that agree on any variable for each valuation $V$ on $\mathcal{A}_n(x)$ since the height $n$ is a sufficiently large number.

If $(x_0,0)$, $(x_0,1)$, $(x_0,2)$, $(x_0,3)$ agree on every variable for some valuation $V$ and $(\mathcal{A}_n(x_0), V) \nvDash \psi$, then we have a valuation $V'(p_t)=V(p_t) \setminus \{(x_0,1),(x_0,2),(x_0,3)\}$ on $\mathcal{C}_n(x_0)$, and $p$-morphism prove the result.

If for every valuation $V$ on $\mathcal{A}_n(x_0)$, we have $(x_0,0)$, $(x_0,1)$, $(x_0,2)$, $(x_0,3)$ don't agree on some variable, then there is a $x_1$ such that $(x_1,0)$, $(x_1,1)$, $(x_1,2)$, $(x_1,3)$ agree on every variable for valuation $V$. We turn to discuss $(\mathcal{A}_n(x_1), V)$ and so on. I am in trouble since I am not sure that this would form proof.

> Does the $\{\mathcal{A}_n(x)\}$ I've constructed satisfy the
> requirements?
>
> If not, do you have any suggestions on the construction of
> $\{\mathcal{A}_n(x)\}$?

Comment: Is this related to finite axiomatization of something?

Comment: Yes. Since every formula $\phi$ which is valid in all $\mathcal{C}_n(s)$ will be valid in some $\mathcal{A}_n(x)$.